# Show tables as objects when doing joins in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

So I have the following SQL that pulls data from three tables:

```
SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions qq
INNER JOIN LNK_Quiz_QuizQuestion lqq ON qq.QuizQuestionID = lqq.QuizQuestionID 
INNER JOIN Quiz q ON lqq.QuizID = q.QuizID
WHERE q.QuizID = 4
```

So it basically gets a list of questions that belong to a quiz via a linker table.

Which gives me the following results **when parsed as JSON**: http://pastebin.com/Jf19axDs

However because I want all the columns and some columns have the same name, the response has some values duplicated e.g. `"IsEditable": [false, true],`

This is really bad, as I need to know if the Quiz or the QuizQuestion is editable and I'd like to have some idea of the object it belongs to.

So the ideal return from the SQL would be something along the lines of:

```
{
    "Quiz": {
        "IsEditable": false
    },
    "QuizQuestion": {
        "IsEditable": true
    }
}, {
    "Quiz": {
        "IsEditable": false
    },
    "QuizQuestion": {
        "IsEditable": true
    }
}
```

How would I achieve this with SQL? I'm using SQL Server.

---

Note: Regarding the use of `SELECT *`, **this for ease of use in this example** and shouldn't be the cause of the problem, because even if I name the columns:

```
SELECT q.IsEditable, qq.IsEditable
```

returns

```
"IsEditable": [false, true]
```

OR even give them aliases:

```
SELECT q.IsEditable AS QuizIsEditable, qq.IsEditable AS QuizQuestionIsEditable
```

returns

```
"QuizIsEditable": false,
"QuizQuestionIsEditable": true
```

---

**Update: After thinking about this some more, it would seem that I would need to split the SQL query up and then create each object separately. Would that be correct?**

Comment: It doesn't matter about the JSON part... it's more to do with the way the objects come back BEFORE they are parsed into JSON.

Comment: Well, in that case - one more reason ***never*** to just use `SELECT *` in your query! Give your columns meaningful names - like `QuizIsEditable` and `QuestionIsEditable` or whatever you like.

Comment: The columns do have meaningful names! If I was using an ORM then the returned data WOULD look like the above. So I'm essentially asking HOW to do that.

Comment: Not sure - how do you convert your SQL rows into JSON? That's the key I think.... SQL Server itself doesn't know anything about "objects" - if you get back the response of your `SELECT` statement, it's just a bunch of rows and columns ....

Comment: Well yes - those columns **STILL** are both called `QuizID` - you need to specify **aliases**: `SELECT QuizID = q.QuizID, OtherQuizID = lqq.QuizID ...`

Comment: Okay, the use of aliases won't solve this issue (see edits to my question). I need some other way to declaring each set of columns for a record as sub-objects keeping there original names intact.

Comment: Take a look at this article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/ for converting SQL data to JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to break this up into 2 queries, there's just no way around it. You won't be able to just json encode a raw result from the database. Select the quiz first as an object in your application, give it a property of 'Questions' whose value will be the result of the second query to get all of the questions. Parse that into json and you should be good.

```
SELECT * FROM Quiz WHERE QuizID = 4;
```

This yields some object like this:

```
var quizQueryResult = db.execute("SELECT * FROM Quiz WHERE QuizID = 4;")

// returns something like this, 
// an array of result objects: [{QuizID: 4, IsEditable: true, etc...}];
var myQuiz = queryResult[0]; //the only result from the DB

var questionsQueryResult = db.execute("SELECT qq.* FROM QuizQuestions qq 
    JOIN LNK_Quiz_QuizQuestion lqq ON qq.QuizQuestionID = lqq.QuizQuestionID 
    WHERE lqq.QuizID = 4;");

// questionsQueryResult is now an array or some collection of QuizQuestions.

myQuiz.Questions = questionsQueryResult;
response.Body = jsonEconde(myQuiz);
```

Comment: @Cameron I have no idea what server side language you are using, so I used some javascripty pseudocode.

Comment: What is `new Quiz(`? I don't see that shown anywhere. Thanks

Comment: @Cameron You asked a question that is simply not possible in a single select query. You mentioned an ORM would do this for you... it would, but it would do this using multiple select statements to construct the nested objects. This is oqaque to the person using the ORM. You have to handle this in server-side code... the code that is calling the database, whatever language it is, and make two separate selects.

Comment: The server-side code I'm using is JavaScript (NodeJS). I get I have to make two select statements, but I'm not following how you glue them together...

Comment: @Cameron updated my answer to remove any need to construct a 'Quiz' object.

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? As I don't see how you use `questionsQueryResult` at the end... you just use `quizQueryResult`

Comment: @Cameron yes, typo. Updated.

Comment: Sweet! I get it now. I should be able to use this to create my own objects now :) Thanks.